# Preserving order from a set to itself

Tags: set-theory

> Let $\langle Q, < \rangle$ be a well-ordered set. 
> Suppose that $f: Q \rightarrow Q$ is a preserving order function, prove that $\forall x \in Q \space : \space x \leq f(x).$

(There's a similar question however it asks regarding an order embedding which is a stronger assumption).

Intuitively speaking, I noticed that if we assume there exists such $x \in Q$ then we can consider $f(x)$ and repeatedly ask the same question about $f(x), f(f(x)), f(\dots(x)\dots)$. This reminds an inductive argument which I struggle to formalize and I believe it stems from a lack of understanding of the well-ordering.

Comment: Try transfinite induction, that is what they are built for

Comment: Take the least $x$ among all $x$'s for which $x>f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

So as I mentioned, well-ordered set are isomorphic to ordinals and build for induction.

Here is the scheme of the transfinite induction:
$$P(x): \forall y < x, \, y\leq f(y)$$

- Initialization: take $m = \min Q, m \leq f(m)$
- Proof for successor: Suppose $P(x)$ is true.
- If $x = s(x’)$ we just need to prove it for $x$ since we have a strong induction. But since $s(x’)\leq s(f(x’)) \leq f(s(x’))$, $x \leq f(x)$.
- If $x$ is not a successor, $\forall y <x$ $y \leq f(y)$ so if we consider the set $A=\{ y \geq x\}$ it has a smaller element which is $x$ and $f(A) \subset A$ (just take complementary) thus $f(x) \geq \min f(A) \geq x$.

Our transfinite induction is complete!